# Replicate an fixed income index in python

Tags: programming, fixed-income, bond, index

I am trying to replicate an fixed income index in python through linear programming. Data for all bonds in the index are available as well as index values. I intend to first create a free portfolio and then use Lasso for variable selection.

Do you have any good literature or can you help me get started?

Comment: Perhaps look at the methodology papers of index providers such as BBG, ICE etc?